# How to create a scrolling or static sidebar menu

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am looking for programming help on how to do a sidebar menu like the one shown at this URL:

[Nettuts Website Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/)

I would like my sidebar to function just like the sidebar on the website, with my own look and feel applied to it. I would like the sidebar to scroll with the page fixed at its own location just as it functions on `Nettuts` website. How would I program this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a `div` with the css statement `position: fixed;` in the css class declaration.

Give any div in your html this CSS styling and you should see it working.

```
position: fixed;
height: 132px;
left: 0;
top: 185px;
width: 24px;
```

Comment: Where would I place the div in my document?

Comment: between the <body></body> tags. Anywhere you wish as the css will move the div to the correct position.

Answer (score 7):

that side bar is nothing more than a div with a fixed position.

```
<style>
.sidebar {
   width: 45px;
   height: 90px;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0px;
   top: 300px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<div class='sidebar'>I'm a sidebar</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p8dFM/

At that point you add elements to the sidebar with whatever functionality you want.

Answer (score 1):

Create a style class like..

```
.class{
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
    width:354px;
    top:185px;
}
```